# Is there a way to display the content of a http link in a feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

If I have www.google.com, and I am displaying it in a feed, is there a way to show the contents of that link the way facebook does? I.e. when I paste the link into the text input, it will display part of the contents of the link and a picture of it?

Edit:
Sorry I meant something like the attached.Do you see how when NBA Jam puts the link there is content underneath? [image]

Comment: AJAX get, can help you with this.

Facebook is getig description from the meta tag, and title of from the title tag.

Using Ajax, you have the URL, and can grab this data

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin for that: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download (check the integration with WebSnapr, http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#websnapr)